# why isnt this database query working correctly

Tags: android

I am trying to search my database to see if a number exists in it, return true if it does and false if not. here is my query

```
    public boolean getPhone(String where){
    Cursor cur = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String [] {ID,PHONE_NUMBER},PHONE_NUMBER + "='" + where + "'",null,null,null,null);

        if(cur.moveToFirst()){

            do{
                String test = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PHONE_NUMBER));
                Log.v("ContactDB", test);
                if(test.equals(where))
                    return true;

             }while(cur.moveToNext());
        }
            return false;
    }
```

when it gets to the do while loop it jumps right over it to return false without even doing it once like it should. If I take the do while loop out, the if(c.movetofirst()) tests false im guessing because that also jumps right to return false.

I just dont get why it is not working right. the database exists and has values in it

Comment: Have you outputted the query and run it manually in sqlite? I'm guessing your where clause is giving an empty result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cur.moveToFirst() is returning false, meaning that there is no data in the cursor.  As for why, I would venture to guess that your database does not contain the data that you are passing into this method.  You should drop a debug in there to verify you are passing in the value that you expect.